# Backbone. Get all views which already exist on the page

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model-view-controller, marionette

Is it possible to get list of views (with their models and events) from the page?

Comment: I'm assuming you want to do this for debugging, you might want to look at [backbone eye](http://dhruvaray.github.io/spa-eye/) which should allow you to do that plus more

Comment: There's also [Marionette Inspector](http://marionettejs.com/inspector) - chrome extension similar to Backbone Eye,but targeted at Marionette applications.